# Python nested dict with lists (or list with dicts) to list of flat dicts for CSV output

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, flatten

I tried searching for similar questions but non of the ones I found do quite what I need.

I am trying to build a generic function that can take the 2 arguments:

1. The object structure
2. A list of (nested) paths

and convert all of the given paths to a list of flat dictionaries, suitable for outputting in CSV format.

So for example if I have a structure such as:

```
structure = {
    "configs": [
        {
            "name": "config_name",
            "id": 1,
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "param name",
                    "description": "my description",
                    "type": "mytype",
                },
                {
                    "name": "test",
                    "description": "description 2",
                    "type": "myothertype",
                    "somedata": [
                        'data',
                        'data2'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "config_name2",
            "id": 2,
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "param name",
                    "description": "my description",
                    "type": "mytype2",
                    "somedata": [
                        'data',
                        'data2'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "test",
                    "description": "description 2",
                    "type": "myothertype2",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And pass the following list of paths:

```
paths = [
'configs.name', # notice the list structure is omitted (i.e it should be 'configs.XXX.name' where XXX is the elem id). This means I want the name entry of every dict that is in the list of configs
'configs.0.id', # similar to the above but this time I want the ID only from the first config
'configs.parameters.type' # I want the type entry of every parameter of every config
]
```

From this, the function should generate a list of flat dictionaries. Each entry in the list corresponds to a single row of the CSV. Each flat dictionary contains all of the selected paths.

So for example in this case I should see:

```
result = [
{"configs.name": "config_name", "configs.0.id": 1, "configs.parameters.type": "mytype"},
{"configs.name": "config_name", "configs.0.id": 1, "configs.parameters.type": "myothertype"},
{"configs.name": "config_name2", "configs.parameters.type": "mytype2"},
{"configs.name": "config_name2", "configs.parameters.type": "myothertype2"}
]
```

It needs to be able to do this for any structure passed, that contains nested dicts and lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a lookup function that searches for values based on your rules (`get_val`). Additionally, this function takes in a match list (`match`) of valid indices which tells the function to only traverse sublists in the dictionary that have a matching index. This way, the search function can "learn" from previous searches and only return values based on the sublist positioning of previous searches:

```
structure = {'configs': [{'name': 'config_name', 'id': 1, 'parameters': [{'name': 'param name', 'description': 'my description', 'type': 'mytype'}, {'name': 'test', 'description': 'description 2', 'type': 'myothertype', 'somedata': ['data', 'data2']}]}, {'name': 'config_name2', 'id': 2, 'parameters': [{'name': 'param name', 'description': 'my description', 'type': 'mytype2', 'somedata': ['data', 'data2']}, {'name': 'test', 'description': 'description 2', 'type': 'myothertype2'}]}]}
def get_val(d, rule, match = None, l_matches = []):
   if not rule:
      yield (l_matches, d)
   elif isinstance(d, list):
     if rule[0].isdigit() and (match is None or match[0] == int(rule[0])):
        yield from get_val(d[int(rule[0])], rule[1:], match=match if match is None else match[1:], l_matches=l_matches+[int(rule[0])])
     elif match is None or not rule[0].isdigit():
         for i, a in enumerate(d):
            if not match or i == match[0]:
               yield from get_val(a, rule, match=match if match is None else match[1:], l_matches = l_matches+[i])
   else:
      yield from get_val(d[rule[0]], rule[1:], match = match, l_matches = l_matches)

def evaluate(paths, struct, val = {}, rule = None):
   if not paths:
      yield val
   else:
      k = list(get_val(struct, paths[0].split('.'), match = rule))
      if k:
         for a, b in k:
            yield from evaluate(paths[1:], struct, val={**val, paths[0]:b}, rule = a)
      else:
         yield from evaluate(paths[1:], struct, val=val, rule = rule)

paths = ['configs.name', 'configs.0.id', 'configs.parameters.type']
print(list(evaluate(paths, structure)))
```

Output:

```
[{'configs.name': 'config_name', 'configs.0.id': 1, 'configs.parameters.type': 'mytype'}, 
 {'configs.name': 'config_name', 'configs.0.id': 1, 'configs.parameters.type': 'myothertype'}, 
 {'configs.name': 'config_name2', 'configs.parameters.type': 'mytype2'}, 
 {'configs.name': 'config_name2', 'configs.parameters.type': 'myothertype2'}]
```

Edit: it is best to sort your input paths by path depth in the tree:

```
def get_depth(d, path, c = 0):
   if not path:
      yield c
   elif isinstance(d, dict) or path[0].isdigit():
      yield from get_depth(d[path[0] if isinstance(d, dict) else int(path[0])], path[1:], c+1)
   else:
      yield from [i for b in d for i in get_depth(b, path, c)]
```

This function will find the depth in the tree at which the path's target value exists. Then, to apply to the main code:

```
structure = {'configs': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'declaration', 'parameters': [{'int-param': 0, 'description': 'decription1', 'name': 'name1', 'type': 'mytype1'}, {'int-param': 1, 'description': 'description2', 'list-param': ['param0'], 'name': 'name2', 'type': 'mytype2'}]}]}
paths1 = ['configs.id', 'configs.parameters.name', 'configs.parameters.int-param']
paths2 = ['configs.parameters.name', 'configs.id', 'configs.parameters.int-param']
print(list(evaluate(sorted(paths1, key=lambda x:max(get_depth(structure, x.split('.')))), structure)))
print(list(evaluate(sorted(paths2, key=lambda x:max(get_depth(structure, x.split('.')))), structure)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I get an invalid syntax:
```
  if (k:=list(get_val(struct, paths[0].split('.'), match = rule))):
```

Comment: @Slav this answer uses an assignment expression which is available in Python3.8 and greater. However, I have edited the post so that it does not use an assignment expression

Comment: WOW! Thank  you! I am going to test it with different data and report back if I find any problems. You sir are a GOD!

Comment: @Slav Glad to help!

Comment: Hi @Ajax1234 . I have edited the OP as I found a bug in your code. Could you take a look at it please? Thanks!

Comment: @Slav What is your desired output from `paths2`? Also, it outputs double because it is designed to provide top level keys with all of this produced descends. Can you clarify this?

Comment: @Slav As a follow up, does order of the input paths actually matter? For instance, in the context of this problem, is there a true difference between `['configs.id', 'configs.parameters.name', 'configs.parameters.int-param']` and `['configs.parameters.name', 'configs.id', 'configs.parameters.int-param']`?

Comment: Hi, my desired output is that both `paths1` and `paths2` return the output of `paths1`.  Now that I think about it - I can just sort the paths by the number of nests they contain, before passing them to the method. But I am curious to know if this can be fixed. EDIT: Just saw your last comment - yes the order does not matter when fetching them, only when outputting to CSV, but I can just pass the DictWriter the original path list, while supplying it with the list of rows from your method (to which I have passed a sorted list of rows)

Comment: @Slav Based on your problem structure, I suggest sorting by the depth of the path target value in the structure. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Hmm. This is interesting approach. I ended up just sorting the list of paths (see my latest edit in OP). Is there a downside of doing it the way I did instead of doing it as in your latest edit? EDIT: I haven't tested but maybe there will be a problem with my approach when I ask for a specific array element, rather than for all?

Comment: @Slav sorting by length would work when you don't have any specified indices in your path. However, if you have something like `['key.0.val.0.target', 'key.val.name1.name2']`, the ordering from a length sort would be  `['key.val.name1.name2', 'key.0.val.0.target']`, however, `'key.0.val.0.target'` is closer to the target value than `'key.val.name1.name2'`. At the very least, there is more ambiguity when indices are involved.

Comment: That is what I thought as well. Thank you again. Will edit the OP with what we discussed.